# PHP - Protected property is not accessible from the same class of Zend 1 library so magic __set() gets used and errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, magic-methods

The application that I am building runs locally but on the staging server flags up:

```
Zend_Form_Exception: Invalid attribute "_name"; must not contain a leading underscore
```

The problem is due to line 500 of /library/Zend/Form/Element.php (Zend version 1) in which is sets:

```
$this->_name = $name;
```

On staging (but not local), the magic __set() method ends up being used which fails because Zend will not allow a property that looks like it is private (by dint of the underscore) to be set by the function used in __set():

```
$this->setAttrib($key, $value);
```

I am trying to work out why the magic method ends up getting used since if -- before line 500 -- I add:

```
if (!property_exists($this, '_name')) die();
```

I can tell that it knows that the property exists. The property is defined in the same class, so essentially:

```
class Zend_Form_Element implements Zend_Validate_Interface {

    protected $_name;

    public function __construct($spec, $options = null) {
         $this->setName($spec);
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->setAttrib($key, $value);
    }
}
```

What reason could there be for the magic method being used rather than just setting `_name` in the normal way?

Comment: Zend Framework 1 suffered a lot of poor design decisions.  Over-reliance on magic getters/setters was one of them.  Without taking the time to properly analyse it my first hunch is you've simply run up against an issue caused by those poor design decisions, or a flat out bug.  If it works on one server but not the other, then check the PHP and ZF versions on both and how they're configured.

Comment: I am having this problem too. Two questions: 1) is your PHP version is PHP 5.4.x? 2) is this problem occurring only for "text" fields?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the reason for using the magic here was. Zend 1 made some interesting design decisions regarding the magic methods (as has been mentioned in other answers).

Regarding your die() statement this is probably not getting called because __isset() is implemented in the class and so property_exists() will return true.

If you are trying to figure out what's going on I'd recommend setting up xdebug.

Comment: Regarding the second point, there does not seem to be an __isset() magic method associated with the class and one would think that whatever would make property_exists() return true should preclude the __set() magic method being called (as long as the property is also accessible).

The problem seems to be that the grandchild class is being called by my code and when I explicitly add a constructor to this grandchild class with `parent::parent::construct()`, the problem disappears. I would rather not edit framework code.

I have Xdebug set up locally but on stage there are setup/security issues

Answer (score 1):

Just to leave it somewhere, as it's definitely an interesting (again) issue. We suspect it's to deal with APC storing the class within the memory, which becomes "corrupted" (for no alternative way to explain it). Simply editing Zend_Form_Element_Text class by inserting one empty line resolved the issue for us. Fun!